# custom page dropped off from templates drop down

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm in a spot of bother and hope there is someone who has had this same issue or knows how to help.

I created a custom page.php 7 months ago, which is linked to a wordpress page via. the templates drop down.

I've noticed this morning, that when I go to the page http://www.cutepinkboutique.com/free-delivery-coupon-page/ it just shows a blank white page and no content.

I went to the admin menu -> pages on wordpress, which exists and can see that the custom page no longer appears in the templates drop down. Bare in mind, this was working fine 2 days ago.

I checked the html file and can see that the line:

```
<?php

/*
   Template name: The Landing Page
*/

get_header(); ?>
```

remains within the HTML file untouched.

So what's changed? Well I updated my theme yesterday and ran a few plugin updates. This morning I rolled back the theme update but this made no difference.

I got in touch with my hosting provider who advised that this could be a theme or a data corruption issue.

Any ideas from the community?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to make page.php a custom template because it is a [default wordpress page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). What if you rename it to template_page.php or some other name?

Comment: Thanks for your response. So are you saying to rename my current template?

Comment: Yes, try to rename your current template and see if that works

Comment: I renamed it to <?php

/*
   Template name: The Landing Page 1
*/

get_header(); ?>

but no difference :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. For some reason, the folder structure had changed and i needed to place it in the themes folder wp-content/themes/mytheme/ folder that existed under public_html and not within the domain folder cutepinkboutique.com/wpcontent/themes/mytheme/